# Get 403 status when using Spring Websocket and SockJS in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I got this error and my web socket cannot run:
[403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76GtP.jpg)

Here is my configure for websocket:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SpringWebSocketConfig extends 
AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/ws-secured/user/");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws-secured/init-api").withSockJS();
    registry.setErrorHandler(new ApplicationStompSubProtocolErrorHandler());
}
```

}

and websocket security:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringWebSocketSecurityConfig extends 
AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
 @Override
 protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry 
messages) {
 messages.simpTypeMatchers(
        SimpMessageType.CONNECT,
        SimpMessageType.MESSAGE,
        SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE).authenticated()
 .simpTypeMatchers(
        SimpMessageType.UNSUBSCRIBE,
        SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT).permitAll()
 .anyMessage().denyAll();

}

 @Override
 protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
  return true;
 }

}
```

For more information, here is my csrf configure in Spring Sec:

```
http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and().authorizeRequests();
http
.csrf()        
    .ignoringAntMatchers("/ws-secured/**")
    .and()
.headers()
    .frameOptions().sameOrigin();
```

I have also pass my csrf token to the header:

```
$stomp.connect('/ws-secured/init-api', {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : csrf_token}, function(data) {
```

I have searched through the Internet but cannot find the answer. I am using Tomcat 7. Do you have any ideas?